# Notation for vector fields on manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I am a bit confused with the way Jack Lee (and my teacher in class too) defines vector fields. For instance, in Introduction to Smooth Manifolds, page 182, Example 8.17, Lee defines a smooth vector field on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ by
$$Y = x \frac{\partial}{\partial y} - y \frac{\partial}{\partial x}.$$
Is this just shorthand for
$$\forall (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} \, \colon \: Y_{(x,y)} = x \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\Big\vert_{(x,y)} - y \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Big\vert_{(x,y)},$$
or am I missing something, i.e., should the $x$ and $y$ multiplying the vector fields $\partial / \partial y$ and $\partial / \partial x$ be interpreted as functions here?

Comment: yes and yes.  This is not the last time you will be annoyed by (necessarily) terse notation in differential geometry :)

Comment: Quick question : why is there a $-$ sign in the definition of the vector field $Y$ ?

Comment: @Odile $Y$ is just an example of a smooth vector field on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$

Comment: @Odile: The $-$ sign is there so that this vector field will be tangent to circles centered at the origin. This is a geometrically pleasing and important vector field.